# Quadratic Sieve

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, analysis, number-theory, factoring

Can anyone explain how Quadratic Sieve (factorization algorithm) works?

I tried reading relevant articles but they didn't include clear explanation / implementation of it.

Comment: I haven't read it in a while: [A Tale of Two Sieves](http://www.ams.org/notices/199612/pomerance.pdf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an outline, an actual implementation is more complicated.

You want to factor $m$ where $m = pq$ , $p$ and $q$ are primes.

if $x^2 - y^2 = m$ then $(x-y)(x+y) = m$ so  $(x-y)$ and $(x+y)$ are factors of $m$.

if $x^2 - y^2 = km$ then $(x-y)(x+y) = km$ so  $(x-y)$ and $(x+y)$ could contain a single factor of $m$ each. One of them could contain all of $m$ which is useless.There are many more ways to find a solution to this problem.

The quadratic sieve tries to construct $x$ and $y$ so that $x^2 - y^2 = km$ then check if $(x-y)$ or $(x+y)$ has one common factor with $m$.

It generates many $x_n$ by $x_n = \lfloor \sqrt{m} \rfloor + n$ , $n = 1\dots$

$x_n^2 - km = (\lfloor \sqrt{m} \rfloor + n)^2 -km = p_1p_2\dots p_a \tag 1$

The right side is factored into primes.

By selecting **some** of the equations to match the primes so that there is an even power of each of them and multiplying the equations together it gets:

$$(x_1x_2\dots x_b)^2 - p_1^{2k_1}p_2^{2k_2}\dots p_a^{2k_a} = Km$$

$(x_1x_2\dots x_b)^2 - (p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\dots p_a^{k_a})^2 = Km \tag 2$

Then it tests if $(x_1x_2\dots x_b - p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\dots p_a^{k_a})$ or 
$(x_1x_2\dots x_b + p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\dots p_a^{k_a})$ has one common factor with $m$. The greatest common divisor (**gcd**) algorithm is used.

In practice a **factor base** is used. This limits the set of primes $p_1\dots p_{max}$ that are used.If the right side of $(1)$ contains factors not in the factor base then that equation is rejected. **Sieving** methods ensure that only small primes are needed in the factor base i.e. **smoothness**.

---

Example: Let $m = 253 =11*23$, $\lfloor \sqrt{m} \rfloor = 15$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & x_n & x_n^2-km & factors & odd\ power & comment\\ 
\hline
1 & 16 & 3 & 3 & 3 & \\ 
\hline
2 & 17 & 36 & 2,2,3,3 &  & is\ square\\
\hline
3 & 18 & 71 & 71  & 71 & too\ large\\ 
\hline
4 & 19 & 108 & 2,2,3,3,3 & 3 & \\
\hline
5 & 20 & 147 & 3,7,7  & 3 & \\
\hline
\end{array}

Row 2 is square but for the sake of the demonstration lets ignore it.

The odd power column contains primes that have an odd power.

Multiplying rows 1 and 4 will give $3^2$ evening up the powers.

$x = x_1x_4 = 16.19 = 304$ , $y = \sqrt{3.108} = 2.3^2 = 18$

$gcd(x-y,m) = gcd(304-18,253) = 11$

$gcd(x+y,m) = gcd(304+18,253) = 23$

Comment: Other QS questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=quadratic+sieve

Comment: Implementation details are complicated, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183183/quadratic-sieve-algorithm

Comment: Hi @arthur , p and q have to be prime? Since in the wikipedia page, they dd not mention this.

Comment: @Bestmat - No, p and q can be composite.