# How the sieving part of quadratic sieve actually works?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am trying to implement quadratic sieve algorithm as it's described in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve).
I understand most of it, except the part of the [sieving example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve#Example_of_basic_sieve).

In the example they use $N = 15347$ with base prime $\{2,17,23,29\}$
Than they build a vector $V$ for the first $100$ values in
$$y(x)=(x+124)^2-15347$$

Than they find what of those values in $V$ are divided by each of the values in the base prime.

They start from $2$ and in the end of the calculation they say:

> Thus, starting at X=1 and incrementing by 2, each entry will be
> divisible by 2. Dividing each of those entries by 2 yields
>
> $V = \begin{bmatrix} 29 & 139 & 529 & 391 & 1037 & 647 & \cdots & 17191 \end{bmatrix}$

Why are they doing this? How is the vector $V$ is used in the end? Can you please provide a better explanation here.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183183): the comments may be useful.